# Index of a mysterious congruence subgroup

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, local-fields

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local number field, $\mathfrak{o}_F$ its ring of integers and $\mathfrak{p}_F$ its maximal ideal. Let $E$ be a quadratic unramified extension over $F$.

Let $G$ be the quasi-split unitary group in 3 variables. Consider the following sequence of open compact subgroups of $G$:

$$K_n = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathfrak{o}_E & \mathfrak{o}_E & \mathfrak{p}_E^{-n} \\
\mathfrak{p}_E^n & 1 + \mathfrak{p}_E^n & \mathfrak{o}_E \\
\mathfrak{p}_E^n & \mathfrak{p}_E^n & \mathfrak{o}_E
\end{array}
\right) \cap G$$

I do not suceed in computing its index in $K_0$, so if anyone has a clue...

Comment: Have you looked at Miyauchi's papers on U(3)?  He works with these groups, and tells you something things about them, I guess enough to compute these indices.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595405/index-of-a-mysterious-congruence-subgroup